# Save function in django/python duplicating entries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm writing a football scoring app for a local league using the same schema as the NFL's gameday DB. I created a function that will eventually run on it's own updating each player's scores.

The problem comes when the function to create a new points record is run it duplicates the entry for each player, there's no error shown or anything, everything runs as expected except for the duplicate values.

here are my views.py:

```
def updatepoints(request):
    actual = get_object_or_404(CurrentWeek, status='active')
    week = actual.week
    season = actual.season
    ptsexist = Puntos.objects.filter(week=week, season=season)
    if ptsexist:
        pts = Player.objects.raw('''SELECT DISTINCT player.player_id,(SELECT (SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_yds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_twoptm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_int))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.rushing_yds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.rushing_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.rushing_twoptm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.fumbles_lost))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_yds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_twoptm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_rec))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.kicking_fgm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.kicking_xpmade))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.fumbles_rec_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.kicking_rec_tds))) AS total,id_puntos FROM player INNER JOIN play_player ON player.player_id = play_player.player_id INNER JOIN game ON play_player.gsis_id = game.gsis_id LEFT JOIN points ON player.player_id = points.player_id AND points.temporada = game.season_year AND "DraftFantasy_puntos".semana = game.week WHERE game.week = %s AND game.season_year = %s AND game.season_type != 'Warmup' AND game.season_type != 'Postseason' GROUP BY player.player_id,points.id_points''', [week, season])
        for obj in pts:
            obj.id = obj.player_id
            obj.points = obj.total
            obj.idpoints = obj.id_points
            form = UpdatePointsForm(request.POST)
            pointsf = form.save(commit=False)
            pointsf.id_points = obj.idpoints
            pointsf.player_id = obj.player_id
            pointsf.temporada = season
            pointsf.semana = week
            pointsf.puntos_ppr = obj.total
            pointsf.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/savepoints/")

def savepoints(request):
    actual = get_object_or_404(CurrentWeek, status='active')
    week = actual.week
    season = actual.season
    ptsn = Player.objects.raw('''SELECT DISTINCT player.player_id,(SELECT (SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_yds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_twoptm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.passing_int))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.rushing_yds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.rushing_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.rushing_twoptm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.fumbles_lost))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_yds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_twoptm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.receiving_rec))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.kicking_fgm))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.kicking_xpmade))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.fumbles_rec_tds))+(SELECT SUM(play_player.kicking_rec_tds))) AS total FROM player INNER JOIN play_player ON player.player_id = play_player.player_id INNER JOIN game ON play_player.gsis_id = game.gsis_id WHERE game.week = %s AND game.season_year = %s AND game.season_type != 'Warmup' AND game.season_type != 'Postseason' GROUP BY player.player_id''', [week, season])
    for obj in ptsn:
        obj.id = obj.player_id
        obj.points = obj.total
        formn = PointsForm(request.POST)
        pointsfn = formn.save(commit=False)
        pointsfn.player_id = obj.player_id
        pointsfn.temporada = season
        pointsfn.semana = week
        pointsfn.points = obj.total
        pointsfn.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/ligas/")
```

the forms.py:

```
class PointsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Points
        exclude = ["player_id",
                   "season",
                   "week",
                   "puntos"]

class UpdatePointsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Points
        exclude = ["id_points",
                   "player_id",
                   "season",
                   "week",
                   "points"]
```

and the models.py:

```
class Points(models.Model):
    id_points = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    player_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    season = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    week = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    puntos = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)

class CurrentWeek(models.Model):
    id_week = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    week = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    season = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="done")
```

I'm really stumped so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you raw query doesn't send the items duplicated?

Comment: Yes, i've reviewed them may times and they are not returning duplicate values